# How do I put content in a tag post template for blogger

Tags: html, tags, widget, blogger

I must admit I am self taught and this might not be the name of this type of template. With that admission out of the way I will do my best to explain my problem. I am trying out new premium responsive templates. I have customized simple things like color codes.

Now I need to put up content and the usual avenues are not showing up in the widget boxes (I can not just go to layout and into the widget manually). I have a few sample posts and have made sure I use corresponding labels but apparently there is step I am missing in order to add the content to the corresponding widget.

***For further clarification: I believe this to be a coding issue as I am using an outside blogger created template. The issue in my estimation is a lack of modification of HTML code somewhere in order to the tags to be recognized by the widgets (created within the template) and for the posts to show up under the correct headlines.

You may need to visit the link to get a vague idea of what I am referring to. If you believe this question does not belong here, perhaps you can be so kind as to refer me to another place(forum ***not blogger***) you feel it more appropriate.

I am not sure what else to include in order for you to be able to help. I can give you the current domain: http://womenofafeather.blogspot.com/#

I appreciate any guidance as I have tried for 2 days to do this on my own and internet searches that have been no help...

Comment: What widgets are you using? Are they external ones? Also, I'm not sure that stackoverflow is the right place to ask this question, as it is not related to coding... (but I'm not a moderator so I will try to help you)

Comment: It is a coding question... They are called tag widgets in the template. This is the first time I have used such a template that the posts or videos do not just show up under the widget headlines. I appreciate your help if you can take a look at the site and this may give a bit more clarity as to what I am referring to. I need to know if I need to modify some HTML or cut an paste URL links. The problem is that my posts(content) once labeled is not showing up under the website widgets headlines and I am not sure what codes to modify or include.

Comment: I still don't get how is it a coding question... What code do you have? What have you tried to do already? This question is to much unspecific and also to much not related to programming, but to the blogger system...

Comment: I suppose I would need help from someone who either knows the template or can take a look at it for better clarification. No disrespect intended I just do not know how else to explain this issue. I am referring to the coding in this template... does this site not help with all issue in coding matters. I know this is not a blogger issue it has to do with me not knowing how to modify the template to show content under the tags widget headlines.

Comment: Just curious have you looked at the this link to get even a vahue idea of what I am trying to describe... http://womenofafeather.blogspot.com/# again thank-you.

Comment: Yes Asera I've looked and I understands the problem. First of all, without the code of the site no one can help you. Also, it seems to be a problem of using the site and not **coding**, which means that it doesn't relates to stackoverflow. I am referring you to the site's rules so you could better understand what content relates to stackoverflow and what doesn't: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. It doesn't mean your question is not a good one, but I think it has nothing to do in HERE. I hope you understand.

Comment: You are correct after reading that link you provided and in combination of your response it does not belong here.... sigh... I will leave up a bit longer in the hopes that someone knows where to at least point me. After that no more posts in here... thanks for your effort.

Comment: Try to ask https://webapps.stackexchange.com/, maybe it is more related (check there in the rules what can be asked there..). Also, you can search for help from google about your problem.

Answer (score -1):

And I irrelevant and self-taught. 
I see you used a handwritten "temblate" 
I think the "widget" you want to place, should be "java or  javascript" and place them manually in the "template". 
Go to your blog and select edit template "html" 
Find the points onto the "widget" and paste code. 
Make sure the size is proportional to the space you give them the first page. 
If you have make this. make sure the "html" the mount point can not be turned off <- ->